# controller function in angular js module doesn't work for the delete operation

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, spring-boot

I am developing a new library management software with spring boot,angular js, and MongoDB as backend. I want to perform crud operation  on MongoDB with that application and for that I referring some open source project with that I can perform create and read operations successfully but can't perform delete and update operations so how can perform  I also made some changes for delete update but can't perform with that so tell me the changes have to perform in order to perform delete.I added this as my own in mybooks.html but the element is not deleting.for that made some changes in mybooks.html and hello.js for delete operation but the element is not deleting

```
<td><form ng-submit="controller.delete()">
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete">
        </div>
</form></td>
```

bookrestcontroller.java

```
package com.sezin.controller;

import com.sezin.model.Book;
import com.sezin.repository.BookRepository;
import com.sezin.repository.UserAccountRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestConditionHolder;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sezin on 3/23/16.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
public class BookRestController {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByTitle/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Book getBookByTitle(@PathVariable String title){
        return repository.findByTitle(title);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByAuthor/{author}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(@PathVariable String author){
        return repository.findByAuthor(author);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/getAll/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBooksByUserName(@PathVariable String userName){
        return repository.findByUserName(userName);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value ="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Book create(@RequestBody Book book){
        if( userAccountRepository.findByUsername(book.getUserName()) != null &&
                repository.findByTitle(book.getTitle()) == null){
            return repository.save(book);
        }
        else
            return null;

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id){


        repository.delete(id);



    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "{id}")
    public Book update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Book book){
        Book updated = repository.findOne(id);
        updated.setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
        updated.setTitle(book.getTitle());
        updated.setYear(book.getyear());
        return repository.save(book);

    }
}
```

securitycontroller.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   /* http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/", "/register.html", "/account").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);*/
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/", "/register.html", "/account", "/api","/delete").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().
            httpBasic().and().
            csrf().disable();

}
```

mybooks.html

```
  <tr>
      <th>BooK_id</th>
    <th>BooK_title</th>
    <th>BooK_author</th>        
    <th>BooK_year</th>
    <th>update</th>
 </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="message in controller.messages">
    <td>{{message.id}}</td>
    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
    <td>{{message.author}}</td>     
    <td>{{message.year}}</td>
    <td><form ng-submit="remove(message.id)" ng-controller="books">
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete">
        </div>
</form></td>
 </tr>
```

hello.js

```
  /**
 * Created by sezin on 3/22/16.
 */
angular.module('hello', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller : 'home',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'login.html',
            controller : 'navigation',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/register', {
            templateUrl : 'register.html',
            controller : 'register',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/mybooks', {
            templateUrl : 'mybooks.html',
            controller : 'books',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).otherwise('/'); 

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    })
    .controller('home', function($http, $cookies) {
        var self = this;
        $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data){
            self.greeting = data;

            self.currentUserName = $cookies.get("username");

            //self.messages = [];
            self.saveBook = function(){
                //var BookRecord = $resource('/account/', {username : self.currentUserName});
                //BookRecord.save(self.book);
                var request = {
                    userName: self.currentUserName,
                    title: self.book.title,
                    author: self.book.author,
                    year: self.book.year
                };
                $http.post('api/books/add', request).success(function(data){

                    if(data){
                        self.success = true;
                    } if(data == null){
                        self.success = false;
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                    //self.messages.push({type:'success', msg: 'Book Saved!'});
                }). error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            };






        });


    })
    .controller('books', function($http, $cookies){
        var self = this;
        self.messages = [];
        self.currentUserName = $cookies.get("username");
        $http.get('api/books/getAll/' + self.currentUserName).success(function(data){

            self.messages = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        self.remove = function(messageId){

$http.delete('messageId');


};


})
    .controller('navigation', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
        var self = this;
        var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {
            var headers = credentials ? {authorization: "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)} :{};

            $http.get('/user/', {headers : headers}).success(function(data){
                if(data.name){
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.username = data.username;
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback() && callback();
                    }

                } else{
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback() && callback();
                    }
                }
            })
        };

        authenticate();
        self.credentials = {};
        self.login = function(){
            authenticate(self.credentials, function () {
                if($rootScope.authenticated){
                    $location.path("/");
                    $rootScope.username = self.credentials.username;
                    $cookies.put("username", $rootScope.username);
                    self.error = false;
                } else{
                    $location.path("/login");
                    self.error = true;
                }

            });
        };

        self.logout = function(){
            $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function(){
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $location.path("/");
            });
        }
    })
    .controller('register', function($resource, $rootScope, $location){
        var self = this;
        self.register = function(){
            var User = $resource('/account');
            User.save(self.user, function(data){
                    self.success = data;


            });
        };

    });
```

Comment: $http.delete() sends a DELETE request to a URL. So it expects a URL as argument, not the hard-coded string 'messageId'.

Comment: which URL I have to provide please analyse well I am following the open source project at GitHub https://github.com/seziny/WebApp

Comment: I did some changes for delete operation in the hello.js file and the mybooks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the DELETE method as GET, pass id param in pathvariable, find the entity by it's id from DB. then delete the entity.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void delete(@PathVariable String id){
    Book book = repository.findById(id);
    repository.delete(book);
}
```

JS

```
$http.get('api/books/delete/'+yourBookId).success(function(data){

    // success 
}). error(function(err){
    // error
});
```

Comment: not working check hello.js file for the delete operation

Comment: I can't log in my application after I did changes in hello.js and mybooks.html for delete operation whats problem for this I am following open source project here is link to project

Comment: can I add messageID at +yourbookid

Comment: you should pass your id in 'yourBookId' like " api/books/delete/23 "   (assuming 23 is your id).

Comment: its the id is taken from messageID from mybooks.html

Comment: yes. The id which you want to delete, you need to pass there

Comment: not working please help urgent follow Github project to perform delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124613/discussion-between-sharan-de-silva-and-ydworld).

Comment: any exception you get in browser inspector.

Comment: can we connect back

Comment: can we connect back

Comment: have look at this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382487/4356983  help me if you can

Comment: have look at this problem stackoverflow.com/q/48429456/4356983